# Python CSV command line tool to import CSV into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I've written my first Python program longer than 15 rows and, of course, it looks terrible.

I'd be very glad to receive comments and suggestion about how to implement a similar tool correctly.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# This script imports the csv data into a mysql database

import csv
import MySQLdb
import os
import sys
import datetime
import subprocess
import time
import logging
import notification

SCRIPT_PATH = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d'
TIME_FORMAT = '%H:%M:%S'
DB_HOST = 'myhost'
DB_USER = 'myuser'
DB_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
DB_NAME = 'mydbname'

logging.basicConfig(filename='csv_import_log.log', level=logging.DEBUG)


def main():
    clear_screen()
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        period = int(sys.argv[1])

        delete_all_csv_in_script_path()

        if period <= 6:
            start_process(period)
        else:
            print 'Wrong option'
    else:
        print 'Add one of the following parameters to retrieve the last relevant ticket number:'
        print ' 1 <-- today'
        print ' 2 <-- yesterday'
        print ' 3 <-- first day of current week'
        print ' 4 <-- first day of current month'
        print ' 5 <-- first day of current year'
        print ' 6 <-- all the data in the db'


def start_process(option):
    '''
    Contains the sequence of the application processes
    '''

    print ' 1 <-- today'
    print ' 2 <-- yesterday'
    print ' 3 <-- first day of current week'
    print ' 4 <-- first day of current month'
    print ' 5 <-- first day of current year'
    print ' 6 <-- all the data in the db'
    if option == 6:
        print 'Importing complete DB'

        # Logging begin time

        begin_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        begin_time_string = 'Process started at ' + str(begin_time)
        logging.info(begin_time_string)

        # File import processes

        delete_all_data_from_db()
        reset_typedoc_ini_file(0)
        start_tool_and_generate_csv()
        kill_tool()
        csv_import_start()

        # Logging end time

        end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        end_time_string = 'Process ended at ' + str(end_time)
        logging.info(end_time_string)
        total_time = end_time - begin_time
        total_time = 'Total import time: ' + str(total_time)
        logging.info(str(total_time))
    else:
        print 'Importing option: ' + str(option)

        # Loggin begin time

        begin_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        begin_time_string = 'Process started at ' + str(begin_time)
        logging.info(begin_time_string)

        # File import processes

        last_ticket_number_and_date = \
            get_last_ticket_number_and_date(option)
        try:
            last_ticket_number = last_ticket_number_and_date[0]
            last_ticket_date = last_ticket_number_and_date[1]
            reset_typedoc_ini_file(last_ticket_number)
        except IndexError:
            print 'No last ticket for chosen date'
            sys.exit()
        except TypeError:
            print 'No last ticket for chosen date'
            sys.exit()
        delete_data_from_db(last_ticket_number, last_ticket_date)
        start_tool_and_generate_csv()
        kill_tool()
        csv_import_start()

        # Logging end time

        end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        end_time_string = 'Process ended at ' + str(end_time)
        logging.info(end_time_string)
        total_time = end_time - begin_time
        total_time = 'Total import time: ' + str(total_time)
        logging.info(str(total_time))


def clear_screen():
    '''
    Cross platform clear screen function
    '''

    os.system(('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear'))


def reset_typedoc_ini_file(ticket_number):
    '''
    Changes ticket number into importantfile.ini
    '''

    file = open('importantfile.ini', 'w')
    file.write('1,data,' + str(ticket_number) + ',1\n')
    file.write('2,otherdata,1,1')
    file.close()
    print 'Added in file importantfile.ini ticket number: ' \
        + str(ticket_number)


def delete_all_csv_in_script_path():
    '''
    Deletes all csv contained into the script folder
    '''

    for file in os.listdir(SCRIPT_PATH):
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            os.remove(file)


def get_last_ticket_number_and_date(period):
    '''
    Returns last ticket number and date based on given period
    '''

    if period == 1:
        try:
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            today = now.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
            today = str(today)
            print 'Checking last ticket number inserted today: ' + today
            mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                                   passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select number, date from docs where date = '%s' order by number desc limit 1"
                            % today)
            last_ticket_number_and_date = cursor.fetchone()
            return last_ticket_number_and_date
        except:
            return '0'
    elif period == 2:
        try:
            yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() \
                - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            yesterday = yesterday.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
            yesterday = str(yesterday)
            print 'Checking last ticket number inserted yesterday: ' \
                + yesterday
            mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                                   passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select number, date from docs where date = '%s' order by number desc limit 1"
                            % yesterday)
            last_ticket_number_and_date = cursor.fetchone()
            return last_ticket_number_and_date
        except:
            return '0'
    elif period == 3:
        try:
            today = datetime.datetime.now()
            monday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=today.weekday())
            monday = monday.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
            monday = str(monday)
            print 'Checking last ticket number inserted this monday: ' \
                + monday
            mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                                   passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select number, date from docs where date = '%s' order by number desc limit 1"
                            % monday)
            last_ticket_number_and_date = cursor.fetchone()
            return last_ticket_number_and_date
        except:
            return '0'
    elif period == 4:
        try:
            today = datetime.datetime.now()
            first_day_of_the_month = datetime.date(today.year,
                    today.month, 1)
            first_day_of_the_month = \
                first_day_of_the_month.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
            first_day_of_the_month = str(first_day_of_the_month)
            print 'Checking last ticket number inserted the 1st of this month: ' \
                + first_day_of_the_month
            mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                                   passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select number, date from docs where date = '%s' order by number desc limit 1"
                            % first_day_of_the_month)
            last_ticket_number_and_date = cursor.fetchone()
            return last_ticket_number_and_date
        except:
            return '0'
    elif period == 5:
        try:
            first_day_of_the_year = \
                datetime.date(datetime.date.today().year, 1, 1)
            first_day_of_the_year = \
                first_day_of_the_year.strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
            first_day_of_the_year = str(first_day_of_the_year)
            print 'Checking last ticket number inserted the 1st of this year: ' \
                + first_day_of_the_year
            mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                                   passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
            cursor = mydb.cursor()
            cursor.execute("select number,date from docs where date = '%s' order by number desc limit 1"
                            % first_of_the_month)
            last_ticket_number_and_date = cursor.fetchone()
            return last_ticket_number_and_date
        except:
            return '0'
    elif period == 6:
        return '0'


def start_tool_and_generate_csv():
    '''
    Opens tool and starts csv generation
    '''

    subprocess.Popen('c:\IT\tool.exe')
    export_finished = False
    previous_total = 0
    equal_checks = 0
    while not export_finished:
        if equal_checks == 4:
            export_finished = True
            print 'Csv generation complete'
        file_sizes = []
        time.sleep(5)
        for file in os.listdir(SCRIPT_PATH):
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                file_sizes.append(os.path.getsize(file))
        new_total = 1
        for value in file_sizes:
            new_total *= value
        if previous_total == new_total:
            equal_checks += 1
        else:
            equal_checks = 0
        previous_total = new_total


def kill_tool():
    '''
    Kills tool
    '''

    try:
        os.system('taskkill /im tool.exe /f')
    except:
        print 'Process Tool not found '


def delete_data_from_db(last_ticket_number, last_ticket_date):
    mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                           passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM docs where number > '%s'"
                   % last_ticket_number)


def delete_all_data_from_db():
    mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                           passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    cursor.execute('truncate docs')


def csv_import_start():
    '''
    Search into the script folder for csv file and imports those files into Mysql
    '''

    for file in os.listdir(SCRIPT_PATH):
        if file.endswith('.csv'):
            if file.startswith('Docs'):
                print 'Importing ' + file
                import_docs(file)
            elif file.startswith('GetCash'):
                print 'Importing ' + file
                import_getcash(file)
            elif file.startswith('GetUti'):
                print 'Importing ' + file
                import_getuti(file)
            else:
                print 'Input error'


def import_docs(docs_csv_file):
    '''
  Imports Docs.csv into mysql
  '''

    mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                           passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    firstline = True
    progress = 0
    with open(os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH, docs_csv_file), 'r') as csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"',
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if firstline:
                firstline = False
                continue
            csv_field_n1 = row[0]
            csv_field_n2 = row[1]
            csv_field_n3 = row[2]
            csv_field_n4 = row[3]
            csv_field_n5 = row[4]
            csv_field_n6 = row[5]
            csv_field_n7 = row[6]
            csv_field_n8 = row[7]
            csv_field_n9 = row[8]
            csv_field_n10 = row[9]
            csv_field_n11 = row[10]
            csv_field_n12 = row[11]
            csv_field_n13 = row[12]
            csv_field_n14 = row[13]
            csv_field_n15 = row[14]
            csv_field_n16 = row[15]
            csv_field_n17 = row[16]
            row[17] = row[17].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n18 = row[17]
            row[18] = row[18].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n19 = row[18]
            row[19] = row[19].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n20 = row[19]
            row[20] = row[20].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n21 = row[20]
            row[21] = row[21].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n22 = row[21]
            row[22] = row[22].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n23 = row[22]
            row[23] = row[23].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n24 = row[23]
            row[24] = row[24].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n25 = row[24]
            row[25] = row[25].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n26 = row[25]
            row[26] = row[26].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n27 = row[26]
            row[27] = row[27].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n28 = row[27]
            row[28] = row[28].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n29 = row[28]
            csv_field_n30 = row[29]
            row[30] = row[30].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n31 = row[30]
            row[31] = row[31].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n32 = row[31]
            row[32] = row[32].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n33 = row[32]
            row[33] = row[33].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n34 = row[33]
            csv_field_n35 = row[34]
            csv_field_n36 = row[35]
            csv_field_n37 = row[36]
            csv_field_n38 = row[37]
            csv_field_n39 = row[38]
            csv_field_n40 = row[39]
            csv_field_n41 = row[40]
            csv_field_n42 = row[41]
            row[42] = row[42].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n43 = row[42]
            row[43] = row[43].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n44 = row[43]
            csv_field_n45 = row[44]
            csv_field_n46 = row[45]
            csv_field_n47 = row[46]
            csv_field_n48 = row[47]
            row[48] = row[48].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n49 = row[48]
            csv_field_n50 = row[49]
            row[50] = row[50].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n51 = row[50]
            row[51] = row[51].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n52 = row[51]
            progress += 1
            print 'Rows imported in docs: ' + str(progress)
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO docs(field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5, field_6, field_7, field_8, field_9, field_10, field_11, field_12, field_13, field_14, field_15, field_16, field_17, field_18, field_19, field_20, field_21, field_22, field_23, field_24, field_25, field_26, field_27, field_28, field_29, field_30, field_31, field_32, field_33, field_34, field_35, field_36, field_37, field_38, field_39, field_40, field_41, field_42, field_43, field_44, field_45, field_46, field_47, field_48, field_49, field_50, field_51, field_52 ) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s  ,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
                           , (
                csv_field_n1,
                csv_field_n2,
                csv_field_n3,
                csv_field_n4,
                csv_field_n5,
                csv_field_n6,
                csv_field_n7,
                csv_field_n8,
                csv_field_n9,
                csv_field_n10,
                csv_field_n11,
                csv_field_n12,
                csv_field_n13,
                csv_field_n14,
                csv_field_n15,
                csv_field_n16,
                csv_field_n17,
                csv_field_n18,
                csv_field_n19,
                csv_field_n20,
                csv_field_n21,
                csv_field_n22,
                csv_field_n23,
                csv_field_n24,
                csv_field_n25,
                csv_field_n26,
                csv_field_n27,
                csv_field_n28,
                csv_field_n29,
                csv_field_n31,
                csv_field_n32,
                csv_field_n33,
                csv_field_n34,
                csv_field_n35,
                csv_field_n36,
                csv_field_n37,
                csv_field_n38,
                csv_field_n39,
                csv_field_n40,
                csv_field_n41,
                csv_field_n42,
                csv_field_n43,
                csv_field_n44,
                csv_field_n45,
                csv_field_n46,
                csv_field_n47,
                csv_field_n48,
                csv_field_n49,
                csv_field_n50,
                csv_field_n51,
                csv_field_n52,
                ))


def import_getcash(getcash_csv_file):
    '''
    Imports GetCash.csv into mysql
    '''

    mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                           passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    firstline = True
    progress = 0
    with open(os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH, getcash_csv_file), 'r') as \
        csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"',
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if firstline:
                firstline = False
                continue
            csv_field_n1 = row[0]
            csv_field_n2 = row[1]
            csv_field_n3 = row[2]
            csv_field_n4 = row[3]
            csv_field_n5 = row[4]
            csv_field_n6 = row[5]
            csv_field_n7 = row[6]
            csv_field_n8 = row[7]
            row[8] = row[8].replace(',', '.')
            csv_field_n9 = row[8]
            csv_field_n10 = row[9]
            csv_field_n11 = row[10]
            csv_field_n12 = row[11]
            csv_field_n13 = row[12]
            progress += 1
            print 'Rows imported in getcash: ' + str(progress)
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO getcash (field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5, field_6, field_7, field_8, field_9, field_10, field_11, field_12, field_13) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
                           , (
                csv_field_n1,
                csv_field_n2,
                csv_field_n3,
                csv_field_n4,
                csv_field_n5,
                csv_field_n6,
                csv_field_n7,
                csv_field_n8,
                csv_field_n9,
                csv_field_n10,
                csv_field_n11,
                csv_field_n12,
                csv_field_n13,
                ))


def import_getuti(getuti_csv_file):
    '''
    Imports GetUti.csv into mysql
    '''

    mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                           passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    firstline = True
    progress = 0
    with open(os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH, getuti_csv_file), 'r') as \
        csvfile:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"',
                                quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
        for row in csv_reader:
            if firstline:
                firstline = False
                continue
            progress += 1
            print 'Rows imported in getuti: ' + str(progress)
            csv_field_n1 = row[0]
            csv_field_n2 = row[1]
            csv_field_n3 = row[2]
            csv_field_n4 = row[3]
            csv_field_n5 = row[4]
            csv_field_n6 = row[5]
            csv_field_n7 = row[6]
            csv_field_n8 = row[7]
            csv_field_n9 = row[8]
            csv_field_n10 = row[9]
            csv_field_n11 = row[10]
            csv_field_n12 = row[11]
            csv_field_n13 = row[12]
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO getuti (field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5, field_6, field_7, field_8, field_9, field_10, field_11, field_12, field_13) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'
                           , (
                csv_field_n1,
                csv_field_n2,
                csv_field_n3,
                csv_field_n4,
                csv_field_n5,
                csv_field_n6,
                csv_field_n7,
                csv_field_n8,
                csv_field_n9,
                csv_field_n10,
                csv_field_n11,
                csv_field_n12,
                csv_field_n13,
                ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Is this code working?

Comment: Yessir. Working and tested. I'm looking for "dos" and "don'ts" of this code and ideas about how to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `import_getuti`,

```
for row in csv_reader:
            if firstline:
                firstline = False
                continue
```

The above code skips first line of the file, but repetitious. To skip a line from any interator, use `next`.

```
next(csvfile)
```

`cursor.execute` can be done as follows,

`row` is a list. Just build a tuple out of it and pass.

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO getuti (field_1, field_2, field_3, field_4, field_5, field_6, field_7, field_8, field_9, field_10, field_11, field_12, field_13)
                VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)', tuple(row[:13]))
```

The following two lines can be moved out of functions and cursor should be passed to functions that need database access.

```
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER,
                           passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_NAME)
cursor = mydb.cursor()
```

Use `str.format` to format stings.

```
print 'Rows imported in getcash: ' + str(progress)
print 'Rows imported in getcash: {}'.format(progress)
```

In function `import_docs`, ',' is replaced with '.' in series of strings that can be done as follows,

```
row[17:34] = [s.replace(',', '.') for s in row[17:34]]
```

If the strings to be processed are non-contiguous in the list and can't be calculated, the whole list can be processed because `str.replace` is safe, it doesn't throw an error if couldn't find the specified old string.

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM docs where number > '%s'" % last_ticket_number)
```

String formatting shouldn't be used in SQL statements for parameter substitution. Pass a tuple.

```
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM docs where number > %s", (last_ticket_number,))
```

`strftime` returns string. No need to call `str` again.

In the `try` block of function `get_last_ticket_number_and_date`,

```
cursor.execute("select number,date from docs where date = '%s' order by number desc limit 1" % first_of_the_month)           
last_ticket_number_and_date = cursor.fetchone()            
return last_ticket_number_and_date
```

non-critical code shouldn't be in `try` bolck and use `else` clause to return values.

```
try:
    cursor.execute("select number,date from docs where date = '%s' order by number desc limit 1", (first_of_the_month,))            
    last_ticket_number_and_date = cursor.fetchone()
except Exception as e:
    print "An error occured: {}".format(e)
else:
    return last_ticket_number_and_date
```

`glob` module can be used to get list of files matching a pattern.

```
for file in glob.glob(os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH,'*.csv')):
    os.remove(file)
```

As no calculation are performed on the input `sys.argv[1]`, it's needless to convert to `int`, just string comparison can be done as `perion == '1'`.

```
if period in '123456':
    start_process(period)
else:
    print 'Wrong option'
```

Rather than dumping all the functions in the main moudle, fuctions should be split by usage and put into separate modules.